# userprincipal.findbyidentity an operations error occurred

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

Okay so, I have been given the responsibility to migrate a website with multiple applications to another server.  That migration went well (all applications working).  However, the performance of that new server was sub par (whole other story).  We decided to migrate it again.  This time everything is working very well-- except one application.
It worked just fine on the first and second IIS servers, but is refusing to cooperate this time around.

I've mirrored all the config settings that I could find from the working server:
windows authentication enabled: check
Impersonation disabled: check
applicationpool settings match: check

I just don't know what I'm missing; why would it work on one server, but not the other.

---

An operations error occurred.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: An operations error occurred.

Source Error:

```
Line 9:          Dim myUsername As String = Right(User.Identity.Name, Len(User.Identity.Name) - InStr(User.Identity.Name, "\"))
Line 10:         Dim ctx = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
Line 11:         Dim myUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, myUsername)
Line 12:         hfValid.Value = "false"
Line 13:         For Each gp As GroupPrincipal In myUser.GetAuthorizationGroups
```

Source File: D:\mghnet1\isOnCall\Default.aspx.vb    Line: 11

COMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +378142
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +36
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +31
System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() +26
System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName) +49
System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName) +150
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer() +1114
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit() +37
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize() +112
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx() +31
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate) +14
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, String identityValue) +73
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue) +28
_Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\mghnet1\isOnCall\Default.aspx.vb:11
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456

---

Please help, none of the other forum posts I've found have posted solutions that work for me.

Comment: Update: so I changed the applicationpool Identity to localsystem and it is working now.  However, on the other server it was just set to applicationpoolIdentity.  Where would that identity be getting priveleges to the AD where this server's applicationpoolIdentity is not?

Comment: had same issue, fixed it by changing the applicationpool Identity to localsystem .  also curious why changing to localsystem fixs it.